# Laravel task schedule: How to wait until previous task finishes to run the next task?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 4 separate commands that needs to be executed in serial order. Ie. Run the first, wait until it finishes and after run the second etc.

I want to use Laravel Schedule, but I'm not sure how I should write it down.

I messed with the after-> and then-> options, but it didn't work.

Any ideas how to go around this?

Here are some trials of nesting using the ->after:

```
    $schedule->command('command:one')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping()->after(function() use($schedule) {
        $schedule->command('command:two')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();
    });
```

Comment: I think you can define some `$flag` variable (in your cache or DB) and check before run command. Or, you can use `Laravel event and listener`.

Comment: the `after()` function should work

Comment: where is the code for your schedule?

Comment: Just added it, refresh the page.